# How to set up cloud with application and connected IoT devices via 3G/LTE

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot

I am a beginner at cloud computing, and I'm hoping to get some guidance or advice as to how I can set up a cloud connected to IoT devices and a running application to control the behavior of these devices.

Firstly, there are 5 devices that have to connected via 3G or LTE because of the distance among the devices, so the way I am thinking of is connecting them to the internet using dynamic public ip addresses and using a dynamic DNS server. It seems like I should be using AWS-IoT service to manage these devices. How should I go about doing that, or is there a better approach? The devices all use MQTT and/or REST API.

The next step is to write an application and I was suggested to use AWS Lambda, am I heading towards the correct direction? How do I link the connected devices on AWS-IoT to AWS Lambda?

I know the question may sound vague but I am still new and exploring different solutions. Any guidance or recommendations for the right step forward is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your devices (or, one of them) has 64-bit CPU (x86 or Arm) that run Linux.

> It's a kind of **70:30** balance where:
>   - 70% of the work needs to focus on building and testing edge-logic.
>   - 30% of the work on the rest (IoT Cloud, Lambda etc).

Here is what I suggest.

1/ Code your edge-logic first! (the piece of code that you want to execute ultimately on your devices).
2/ Test it on-the-edge by logging on to the devices (if you can) via SSH and running it.
3/ Once you have that done, 70% of the job is over.

4/ Rest 30% is to complete the jigsaw in cloud. Best place to start: [Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/getting-started-create-function.html) and [Greengrass](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/quick-start.html).
5/ To summarize it all, you will create greengrass components on cloud, install AWS Greengrass Core software on your device, followed by deploying your configuration on your device over-the-air (OTA).

Now, you can use any MQTT client (or) biult-in MQTTTester of AWS IoT -> Test wizard to send a message to your topic to trigger your edge-logic on the device!

Good luck!

cheers,
ram